# How can I import .cer in SAP Commerce Cloud

Tags: certificate, cloud, sap-commerce-cloud, jks

I am using SAP Commerce Cloud, in Public Cloud. And I am trying to insert a .cer file to make rest calls to API Gateway.

I read about importing it in java using command lines to import to keystore.

But, I don't know how to do it in the SAP Commerce Cloud

Comment: which operating system are you using over cloud,I guess it should be linux

Comment: yes, Linux, but it is a PaaS (SAP) so I don't configure Cloud's OS. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install a certificate in a keystore. please follow the steps -

1. Create the keystore (if not created) using the below command

   ```html
    keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /<path_to_the_pfx>/<pfx_name>.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore /<path_to_the_keystore_to_be_created>/<name_of_the_keystore>.jks -deststoretype JKS
   ```
2. You can control the keystore credentials as below:

   a) sso.keystore.location - The path to the keystore (in this way the keystore can be repo managed)

   b) sso.keystore.password - keystore password (default is *changeit*)

   c) sso.keystore.privatekey.alias - Alias of the private key
3. Import the certificate using the below command

```html
keytool -importcert -alias <alias_of_the_certificate> -file /<path_of_the_cert>/<name_of_the_cert>.cer -keystore /<path_to_the_keystore_to_be_created>/<name_of_the_keystore>.jks
```

To remind again, the keystore (with the installed certificate) can be repository controlled as well using the `sso.keystore.location`.

Alsternatively, if your question is to enable the REST calls from the Commerce cloud environment, please follow the steps mentioned [here](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_CLOUD_PUBLIC_CLOUD/0fa6bcf4736c46f78c248512391eb467/9db9dcaae04243aa8b721492323ec27c.html?locale=en-US&q=certificate).
Hope this helps.